# PRISM: How to implement RegisterViewForNavigation inside Module's Initialize method?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism, modularity

I register my module views in the Initialize method of module class in this way;

```
//CalendarModule.cs
public void Initialize() 
{ 
   _container.RegisterType<object, CalendarModuleView>(nameof(CalendarModuleView));               
}
```

And I load my modules by calling `ModuleManager.LoadModule("CalendarModule");`.
After module initialized, I navigate to my newly loaded module;

```
_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainContentRegion, "CalendarModuleView");
```

So far there is no problem. Everythig works just I expected. I can navigate through all on-demand modules.

But when I try to replace view registration with `_container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<CalendarModuleView>();` I get following error during module loading;

> An exception of type 'Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException'
>   occurred in Prism.Wpf.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An exception occurred while initializing
>   module 'CalendarModule'.
>
> Inner Exception: {"Could not load file or assembly 'Prism.Unity.Wpf, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=91a96d2a154366d8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Prism.Unity.Wpf, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=91a96d2a154366d8"}

I wonder if `RegisterTypeForNavigation<T>` container extension method does the same work with `RegisterType<object, T>(nameof(T))` container method. If yes, what causes preceeding error? Thanks!

> FYI: My modules' initialization mode are OnDemand.
>
> I use Prism.Unity as DI container.

Comment: Have you deployed the Prism.Unity.Wpf.dll. Does it exist in the folder where you start the application from?

Comment: I suspect you use different projects for `CalendarModule` and the main application? If so, try updating the prism nuget packages for each one.

Comment: @Domysee Yes you are right. My modules are separate projects inside a solution. I realized the main projects' packages were old. After nuget update, the problem was solved. Thank you!

Comment: @T.Y.Kucuk I've added it as answer, with a bit more detail to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because the **packages** of the **main project** are not the same **version** as the one referenced in the **module**.

Visual Studio copies only the assemblies referenced in the main project to the output directory.

Since the assembly of your **module** expects a prism assembly with a higher version number, it throws the exception you mentioned.

Updating all packages should resolve the issue.